# How to create SharePoint Site definition with custom lists using WSPBuilder?

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder, wsp, site-definition, custom-lists

I'm using WSPBuilder and I want to create a site definition this site definition contains some custom list definition (some list creates based on "Custom List" template).
The site contains also some files the will copied to `_layouts` folder (which I know how to include it the `.wsp` file).
My request here is how i can create the site definition and it's `onet.xm`l please a feature that creates some lists based on "Custom List", and when i create a site using the site definition it will create all pages and do some stuff through site provisioning class?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up the website with the customs lists the way you want it to be in your browser, and use the [SharePoint Solution Generator](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2006/11/11/SharePoint-Solution-Generator-_2D00_-part-1_3A00_-create-a-site-definition-from-an-existing-site.aspx) to create the site definition.
Because the SharePoint Solution Generator is part of the [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Tools: Visual Studio 2008 Extensions, Version 1.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bf65b28-06e2-4e87-9bad-086e32185e68&displaylang=en) this method has one drawback: no WSPBuilder-support.
But when you deploy the SharePoint Solution Generator's Solution, you will find all the files you need for WSPBuilder in the /bin/debug directory.

Comment: I know how to do it with VSeWSS, but I need it here using WSPBuilder. anyway thank you for your reply.